# What is a plugin project in liferay

Tags: liferay

I'm new to liferay. And I've some basic question that what is liferay all about. What is a liferay plugin project or service builder project? Is liferay any framework,GUI tool, a content manager or WHAT?

I know that you guys are not engaged with this tool in this BLOG but still somehow it is related to java. So please guys help me.

Comment: Tell me in brief that - what I can do using liferay ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried reading the [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) tag-wiki on stackoverflow? Just hover your mouse over it and you will have answers to all your questions. And if you want more just click on the pop-up and you would also find details about how to learn more about Liferay.

Still as per the norms of answering, here are some brief answers to your question:

> Is liferay any framework,GUI tool, a content manager or WHAT?

Liferay is an open source JSR 286 compliant web-portal and social platform, written in Java. It includes content-management and more. It has different plugins known as portlets like Blogs, Forums, Document management, Content management etc.

> What is a liferay plugin project or service builder project?

Plugin projects are nothing but small components/applications/widgets that run in the portal. Some might have UI and others might run in the backend.

Service Builder is a framework in liferay to ease development of services which might include service to access database, web-services, json web-services.

Everything else is given in the tag-wiki and the wiki also includes links to official resources if you wish to use/develop in liferay.

Answer (score 0):

***plugins are features which developers add them to portals like liferay.
for example:
liferay hooks are defined to do some tasks, like user's authentication, adding users, etc .. and we want change (override) that hooks, so we need develop ext plugins to do this for us.***